# How to use trusted connection with GO MSSQL package denisenkom/go-mssqldb?

Tags: sql-server, go

Can I use `trusted connection` in the connection string to connect to MS-SQL? I'm using [denisenkom/go-mssqldb](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb)?

This is a sample connection string that I see from an article:

`server=localhost;user id=sa;password=SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password;`

The [documentation section](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb#connection-parameters-and-dsn) does not mention about the `trusted connection`.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: ```trusted_connection=true``` in the connection string did not work.

Comment: I would assume "did not work" came with an error message? I don't know anything about GO so I have no idea if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string for Windows Authentication looks like this:

```
"server=localhost;user id=;"
```

The value for "user id" parameter is blank and the "password" parameter is not used in the connection string.

This closed issue [Trouble connecting with Active Directory authentication](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/issues/475) from the GitHub repo provides more details about how Windows authentication works than the official documentation and examples.